# Invoke an exe from PowerShell and get feedback on success or failure

Tags: powershell

How can I run an executable in PowerShell and through an if statement determine whether it succeeded or failed?

More specifically I'm trying to get devenv.exe to build a solution from a PowerShell script and I need to know whether it succeeded or failed. By failed, I mean that the build has failed and I'm assuming devenv is sending something out to the shell (possibly in the `stderr` stream?)

I tried using `&`, `Invoke-Expression` and `Invoke-Item` and managed to get all of them to run the exe. But I was never able to get feedback on success / failures.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use msbuild.exe to build the solution instead of devenv.exe?

Comment: The only reason is that I'm not proficient enough in using msbuild. I do have a build machine building my solutions but I don't know how to reuse the build definitions for my local machine :|

Comment: If you want to give it a try here's a reference to how to use msbuild for building solutions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx

Comment: Thanks Filburt. Will definitely give it some time.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Have you tried using the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable?  It will contain the exit code of the last .exe that was invoked.

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/errorlevel-equivalent/

Comment: That did the trick. $lastexitcode -eq 0 when successful, 1 when building failed. :)

Comment: Works great interactively. However, I wanted to let the prompt indicate whether last command succeeded or not; `$LastExitCode` only changes when running executable, since functions and CmdLets don’t have “exit code”; having that in prompt may be misleading, because I cannot judge whether the exit code came from last statement. I wish CmdLets always resets this variable.

Comment: All my script is in Powershell and for a section, it would not return $LastExitCode. The same command if ran from command would return %ERRORLEVEL%. $? saved my day

Answer (score 19):

```
.\YOUREXE.exe
if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "The last PS command executed successfully"
} 
else 
{
    Write-Host "The last PS command failed"
}
```