# Detecting error after a powershell statement is executed

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I am using powershell to run `sqlplus` and I would like PowerShell to detect if there are error after the script was run and to perform some action instead of me looking at the result file.

```
& 'sqlplus' 'system/myOraclePassword' '@Test' | out-file 'result.txt';
```

Normally in DOS, there is %errorlevel% when the command encounters error and I wonder if there is similar stuff in PowerShell?

Of course, I can read the log file myself but sometimes, thing got too routine and I may forget.

My Test.sql:

```
select level from dual
connect by level<5;
select 10/0 from dual;
quit;
```

There is clearly a division by zero error. The result.txt captures it but I would like powershell to detect it as well

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Apr 27 16:24:30 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu Apr 27 2017 16:17:34 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options


     LEVEL
----------
     1
     2
     3
     4

select 10/0 from dual
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Does the powershell statement return an errorlevel after the statement is executed like DOS?

I have tried:

```
& 'sqlplus' 'system/myOraclePassword' '@Test' | out-file 'result.txt';
if (errorlevel 1)
{ write-host error;
}
else
{ write-host ok;
}
```

But that has caused syntax error?

> errorlevel : The term 'errorlevel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if  a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

What is a proper way to check error in powershell?

**UPDATE**

I used this:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 )
{ 
write-host error;
}
else
{ 
write-host ok;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `if (errorlevel 1)` with `if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1)`

Comment: You will also need to add [`whenever sqlerror exit failure` or `whenever sqlerror exit 1`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#SQPUG135) to the top of you SQL script, otherwise SQL\*Plus will just exit normally when it gets to the quit and the shell won't know anything was wrong. But you can only really get success/failure, not the actual error (1476 here) - you can `exit sql.sqlcode` but most shells will wrap that at 256 which isn't helpful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke an exe from PowerShell and get feedback on success or failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081795/invoke-an-exe-from-powershell-and-get-feedback-on-success-or-failure)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thank you, Alex. Got it!! No wonder

Comment: @AlexPoole: My apologies for coming back to your comment adding whenever sqlerror exit failure to the top of sql script. At first I thought it would solve the issue, but after looking more closely, $LASTEXITCODE is still 0 which meant it either has not received the error flag from the sql or sql does not consider a division by zero a sqlerror. Could you shed some more light on that for me?

Comment: I don't use PowerShell, but I would *guess* that you're seeing the exit code from `out-file` instead, maybe. What happens if you remove that, or use `>` redirection instead? You may need to ask a new question about that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are invoking an *executable*, you probably want to check for the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable or the *return value* of sqlplus. In PowerShell each variable has a `$` prefix.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if all he's interested in is whether or not it "succeeded" (exited with a zero error code), rather than with the specific error code that it exited with, he can also test `$?`, which will be `$true` for a zero error code (success), and `$false` for a non-zero exit (failure).

Comment: @Martin Brandi: $LASTEXITCODE works but what value should I check against? and how do I capture the return value of sqlplus if sql itself throw out an error code?

Comment: The values you check against are defined by the sqlplus command/program - check the documentation for that. It should also tell you what the return will be in the event of an SQL error.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: true in my question but eventually, I would love to capture the error code from the sql script if possible

Comment: @user1205746 - per Alex Poole in the comment to the question, you will have to edit your SQL script to accommodate that. Again, that's an SQL/sqlplus issue, not a PowerShell issue; you need to check the relevant documentation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You are right, `$?` would be also sufficient.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: what I meant was whether $LASTEXITCODE would capture any error code that sql/sqlplus threw out?

Comment: @user1205746 - `$LastExitCode` captures the exit code of the most recently run external executable. If your SQL script is written to exit with a specific value in the event of a certain type of SQL error, that value will be found in `$LastExitCode`, just like it would have been in `%ERRORLEVEL%` in a classical batch script.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: awesome! thank you Jeff for the clarification