# Capture LastExitCode of TreeSizePro

Tags: powershell, error-handling, executable

We're trying to determine if TreeSizePro failed or succeeded. The following code should to that according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081795/invoke-an-exe-from-powershell-and-get-feedback-on-success-or-failure):

```
$LASTEXITCODE = 0

&$TreeSizePro /NOGUI /DATE /EXPAND 4 /SIZEUNIT 3 /SORTTYPE 0 /EXCEL $File /SHEETNAME "Data" /SCANPATH "S:\"

if ($?) {'Success'} else {'Fail'}

$LASTEXITCODE
```

Now when I use incorrect arguments or make an error, the result is always the same: `Success` and `0`. This indicates that the error handling didn't work properly.

What is the best way to determine if the command failed or succeeded?

Comment: Do you get the same results with a different application? Might be TreeSizePro returning `0` even when it fails?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too...