# Running exe in powershell and return code when cancelling

Tags: powershell, exe, return-code

I am using a powershell script which runs an exe, let's say something like this :

```
$myfile = "myapplication.exe"
Start-Process $myfile -Wait

$?
```

But, if I cancel the execution (let's say that I don't agree to the terms, etc...) the return code will be TRUE. 
However, I need the script to say that "The user canceled the operation" and end the script then.

Unforunately, i do not know how to catch this "error" (which is not one of course)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081795/invoke-an-exe-from-powershell-and-get-feedback-on-success-or-failure

Comment: Try `$aux = Start-Process $myfile -Wait  -PassThru` and then check `$aux.ExitCode`. There is too few info on what `myapplication.exe` returns owing to various  user's response.