# ExitCode always has null does not show the actual return value from exe

Tags: c#, powershell, return, return-value

I am calling my exe from powershell script like shown below.

```
$file = $PSScriptRoot + "\executor.exe"
$code = (Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden $file -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $Logfile).StandardOutput.ToString;
$nid = (Get-Process "executor.exe").id
Wait-Process -Id $nid

if ($code -eq 1) {
    LogWrite "Execution succeeded"
} else
{
    LogWrite "Execution Failed"
}
```

I have a int main function in my exe program which would return 1 on success, and 0 on failure.
When i try to get the ExitCode(using $LASTEXITCODE) from powershell script it always shows null(neither 1 nor 0), But my exe is returning 1 as expected.
How do i capture the return value of exe in powershell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke an exe from PowerShell and get feedback on success or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081795/invoke-an-exe-from-powershell-and-get-feedback-on-success-or-failure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.FileName = # path to your exe file

# additional options:
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $false
$psi.WindowStyle = "Maximized"


$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $psi
$p.Start() | Out-Null # returns $true if the process started, $false otherwise
$p.WaitForExit()

# here's the exitcode
$exitCode = $p.ExitCode
```

Create the process start info, to specify the executable path, and additional options. It's important to use `.WaitForExit()` to wait until the process finishes.

What you have tried doesn't get the app exitcode, but what the application write to standard console, which, in your case, I assume is nothing. If you could modify the exe to write to the console, what you did would work.

Comment: exit code is returning a negative value -532462766 for successful case, when i used the above code.

Comment: @RemSan, this code is fully tested and I have it working in several different places, with several different applications. Have you tried to get the retval from your application with a different method? Have you tried this code with a well known application and checked that it returns what you expect? The problem is in your application. In general 0 is "no error" and something else is "error", but you can return whatever you want. I don't mind what you do, but it can be misleading not to confirm that this solution works. Please, explain why you think your app doesn't return that number.