# How to handle exit code for silent installation through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using a silent installation command to install software. I am running this command from powershell using the below command:

```
$install= 'C:\PQR\Installation\xyz.ps1 -silentInstall -abcFolder C:\lmn -Folder C:\log -aRManagement -aHardening -rebootIfNeeded'

Invoke-expression $install
```

How to check if the installation is completed successfully or not. Please help me how to handle the above piece of installation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081795/invoke-an-exe-from-powershell-and-get-feedback-on-success-or-failure

Answer (score 0):

Powershell scripts after execution return the status of execution, which is referred to as "return code" or "exit code". A successful script execution returns a 0 while an unsuccessful one returns a non-zero value that usually can be interpreted as an Error Code.

Use the command Exit $LASTEXITCODE at the end of the powershell script to return the error codes from the powershell script.

Example:

```
Powershell script for copying file to a folder
$dest ="C: est"
New-Item $dest -type directory -force
$source ="c:samplefile.txt"
Copy-Item $source $dest
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```